# ACF gallery & bootstrap colls and rows

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, twitter-bootstrap

I've code to display ACF gallery:

```
<?php 

$images = get_field('portfolio');

if( $images ): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                     <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumb_front']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
                </a>
                <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And I need to wrap every 4 item `<div class="col-lg-3">` into the `<div class="row">` How can I do this, guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option would be to simply check if you are on every fourth iteration. Please see the following for an illustration, I haven't tested this but see the basic idea.

```
<?php 

$images = get_field('portfolio');

if( $images ): ?>

        <?php foreach( $images as $key => $image ):

          if (($key + 1) % 4 == 0) { ?>
             <div class="row">
          <?php } ?>

             <div class="col-lg-3">    

                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                   <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumb_front']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
                </a>
                <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>

             </div>

          <?php
          if (($key + 1) % 4 == 0) { ?>
            </div>      
          <?php }
          endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Make some corrections and now it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per the ACF documentation, the below code is for ACF GALLERY.

```
<?php 

$images = get_field('gallery');

if( $images ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                     <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                </a>
                <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I see, you also doing the same kind of things here. what was wrong here. do you implement your code?